# how to work delete query in wordpress 4.7

Tags: wordpress

Im trying to work delete query in wordpress.
im list all values from table(test)and create delete link to all view values.`<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/delete?id=<?php echo $user->id;?>">Delete</a>`

and Im create anew page delete.php.
Code is :
`<?php global $wpdb; 
$id=$_POST['id'];
$r=$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM test WHERE id=$id"));?>`

after running page not found error message is display??

Comment: How you're doing this? Did you create a page in wordpress admin panel in pages section with name 'delete'? If yes! then you should also create a page template and assign to this 'delete' page first.

Comment: yes sir.but not work.

Answer (score 0):

if you have created a template file called delete and assign that template to one of the wp pages. then in the href you should pass:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_page_by_title('your wp page  name'));?>?id=<?php echo $user->id;?>">Delete</a>"
```

and use GET insted of POST.

Comment: try this query     $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM test WHERE id=%d",'$id'));

Comment: Are you getting id on another page? and did you create a page in wp-admin or it is just php page??

Answer (score 0):

Why not using wp_delet_post?

Like it says here
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post

Comment: sorry im beginner of wordpress..how to use wp_delete_post in my code...

Comment: Here's a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691259/pass-id-from-form-to-delete-function

Comment: iam using this code :  global $wpdb; 
$id=$_POST['id'];
 $wpdb->wp_delete_post('test',$id); is it correct or not?